# Unable to import module from Python

Tags: python

I am trying to import

```
from app.idol.IP import CONTENT_IP_ADDRESS, CONTENT_PORT
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testcontent.py", line 1, in <module>
    from contentactions import get_dbs
  File "C:\Code\Python\xxxxx\app\idol\content\contentactions.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app.idol.IP import CONTENT_IP_ADDRESS, CONTENT_PORT
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

See directory structure. 
[image]

Comment: every python package should have `__init__.py` file (may be empty) inside of it, on each level, so your `app` directory should have `__init__.py` file in it

Comment: My app directory does have `__init__.py` in it.

Comment: and so does `app/idol`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All imports are relative to the directory where you run Python. From your screenshot it is clear that you are running `testcontent.py` from `app\idol\content` rather than `main.py` at the source root, so it fails to find the subdirectory `app` within `app\idol\content`.

You can instead run Python from `C:\Code\Python\K2Associates` like this:

```
python app\idol\content\testcontent.py
```

Comment: It appears that you're missing `__init__.py` inside the `idol` sub-directory too.

Comment: So I have moved testcontent.py to the same dir as main.py and added the __init__.py to idol directory. Its working now.

Answer (score 0):

`__init__.py` is imported using a directory. if you want to import it as app you should put `__init__.py` file in directory named app

another option is just to rename `__init__.py` to `app.py`